# check if checkbox has been checked using ScrewDefaultButtons plugin

Tags: jquery, checkbox

If I wanted to check if an ordinary checkbox has been checked, I would use something like the following:

```
$('#mailformagb').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert('code');
    }
});
```

However, this isn't working with the ScrewDefaltButtons plugin.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the code

Comment: What code? this is exactly what i tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event handler is incorrect as you're not actually clicking the checkbox.  You're clicking a div that was made by the plugin.  You need to handle the change event instead...

```
$('#mailformagb').on("change", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        alert('code');
    }
});
```

Also, checked is a property of the checkbox element, so there's no need to use jQuery to get the checked state.  Accessing the DOM element property is more efficient and quicker (and I think just looks nicer too :p )

Comment: Nice one! good to know for the future, since the plugin itself is kickass.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get all checkbox's event, You should use like

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    alert('code');
}
});
```

Comment: That is not what I asked.

Comment: @BlekStena are you dynamically creating the checkboxes?

Comment: It's not a checkbox.  It's a checkbox plugin.  See my answer below to see the difference explained.